# Raw input HANDLE validity after device removal

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

My question is quite simple, but I can't seem to find any documentation on it.
After receiving a [WM_INPUT_DEVICE_CHANGE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645591(v=vs.85).aspx) message when a device is removed, until what point will the HANDLE to that device be valid?

Does it stay valid even when the device is removed and get reused when it is added again? Or does it get cleaned up after calling DefWindowProc?

I am doing most of the input processing in a background thread, so this small detail can potentially break a lot of stuff.

Comment: It should not matter. You implement proper error checking for every API call and it's gonna be OK.

Comment: @drop it really does matter. You can't expect success if you use stale handles.

Comment: Handles are valid until they are closed. Of course the object behind the handle may have been disconnected but the handle itself can live longer.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Yes of course, but it's that "may" and "can" that I want to clarify

Comment: @Drop Until the handle gets reused by another device, and then all hell breaks loose.

Comment: The device has been removed. What are you planning to do with it?

Comment: So, the question you are asking is "do I close the handle, or does Windows close the handle" ?

Comment: @HarryJohnston No, the question is "When does Windows close the handle"

Comment: Windows doesn't close the handle. You have to.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan That seems odd, since the handle was not created by me. Do you have a link to any documentation that specifies this (which is kind of the whole point of this question).

Comment: Ok, you are right. I don't see how you can expect to use the handle after you return from the message handler.